# Siesta: Child resources

Tags: json, rest, swift2, siesta-swift

I am having difficulties understanding how does Siesta figure out the child of a resource. For example I have the following events resource:

#### JSON returned by "/events"

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "events": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "type": "meeting", 
            "eventDate": "2015-08-20", 
            "notes": "fadsfasfa", 
            "title": null
        },{
            "id": 2, 
            "type": "game", 
            "eventDate": "2015-08-31", 
            "notes": "fdsafdf", 
            "title": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Sadly, calling "/events/1" for example, does not return the event with id=2. Is there a way to tell Siesta which event has the id=2?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by “calling” /events/1?

Comment: Yes, sorry. What I meant was to call Service's resource("/events") function.

Comment: Are you having trouble trying to get /events? Or are you trying to navigate from a successfully populated /events resource to an /events/1 resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have:

```
let events = myService.resource("/events")
```

Then you can navigate from the `/events` resource to the `/events/2` resource like this:

```
let event = events.child("2")
```

That will give you the same object as if you had asked for `myService.resource("/events/2")`.

To extract that `2` from the JSON, use normal Swift JSON parsing techniques. (Siesta doesn’t apply any special inspection or interpretation to the JSON once it’s parsed.) I recommend using the SwiftyJSON library for easier JSON traversal. For example, it lets you do something like this to extract those event IDs and get the child resources:

```
let allEventResources =
    JSON(events.jsonDict)["events"]
        .arrayValue
        .flatMap { $0["id"].string }
        .map(event.child)
```